# @NotEmpty not displaying customised exception message

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator

I used @NotEmpty (hibernate validator) annotation on a variable. created messages.properties file where I put proper entry using "AnnotationName.objectName.variable=string_to_be_displayed". Still I get default error message "may not be null". In spring config servlet, also I binded messages.properties. But no success. please help. I tried many times.

attaching screenshot of log[image]

Response body is : 
[image]

Comment: I renamed "messages.properties" to "ValidationMessages.properties". Now, in the log, "ValidationMessages found" gets displayed, previously "ValidationMessages not found" was displayed(refer to the 1st screen shot) ...still issue is not resolved. not getting the customized exception messages !!! Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last I found the solution of my problem.

To display customised messages, follow this :

```
@NotBlank(message = "your messages")
private String variableName;
```

You can use (messege="...") with every hibernate validator defined annotations, eg. `@Range`, `@Size`, `@NotEmpty`, etc.

No need to create any `ValidationMessages.properties` file or `messages.properties` file for your own. No need to do anything in `spring-context.xml` file for binding.

You may follow this [link](http://mrbool.com/knowing-the-hibernate-validator-part-2/21878#ixzz3IrBlDsZK) for more knowledge on this issue. 
Enjoy coding with your own messages !

Answer (score 0):

Please put your messages.properties file user src/main/resources folder